# Humans genetic/phylogenetic "next relative" in central Europe?

Tags: zoology, phylogenetics

What species in [central Europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Europe#States) in the phylogenetic tree shows the closest difference in time to the most recent common ancestor with *Homo sapiens*?

Comment: Could you define central Europe?

Comment: What do you mean by "next relative"?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I understood the question. Is the following your question?

> Among all species living in central Europe, which one is the most closely related to *homo sapiens*?

**Source of information**

[opentreeoflife.org](http://www.opentreeoflife.org/) (nice vizualisation on [OneZoom.org](http://www.onezoom.org/)) is one of the most update synthesis of existing research inn phylogenetic reconstruction. I base my answer in consideration of [the tree on OneZoom.org](http://www.onezoom.org/life.html?init=zoom#Primates).

**Answer**

Outside *Homo sapiens*, there is no living primates (or any other *[Euarchonta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euarchonta)*) in Central Europe. The sister branch of primates include [*Lagomorpha*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagomorpha) (Hares and Rabbits) and *[Rodents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodent)* (mice, rats, squirrels, prairie dogs, porcupines, beavers, guinea pigs, hamsters, and capybaras). In other words, any *Lagomorpha* and any *Rodents* are all equally related to any *Primate* (incl. *Homo sapiens*). Their Most Recent Common Ancestor (MRCA) lived about 75 millions years ago.

Examples of species of lagormorpha and rodents that live in Europe include *[Mus musculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_mouse)*, [Rattus norvegicus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_rat), *[Lepus europeanus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_hare)* and [Sciurus vulgaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_squirrel).

**How about Hedgehogs?**

Hedghogs are *[Insectivora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insectivora)* and they are a sister group to all *primates*, *lagomorpha* and *rodents*. Their MRCA lived about 80 million years ago. So, no there are species currently living in Europe that are more closely related to us than hedgehogs.

**Note**

The term "next relative" does not mean anything! You might want to understand your understanding of phylogeny with an introductory course.

Comment: Yes this was my question. Would it "theoretically" be possible to measure the individual distances of each Lagomorph or Rodent species to the MRCA? I mean it is for instance known that some are more "archaic" then others. So that the question would be what is the most archaic of all Lagomorpha and Rodents? I see that the answer ideally would theoretically require a complete knowledge of the MRCA, nut maybe some guess is possible?

Comment: For example *Aplodontia rufa*
 (if it only lived in Centraleurope) would be a candidate in the sense of my question.

Comment: *Aplodontia rufa* lives in north America (California, Oregon, Washington and British Columbia). I added examples of species in my answer.

Comment: Nice answer. I would just note that OneZoom.org doesn't assemble the data themselves; they get it from http://www.opentreeoflife.org/ (as acknowledged in http://www.onezoom.org/about.html). They do a nice job of presenting it though, which is also important!

Comment: I have updated the question and choose one possible specification of the heuristic term "next relative".

Comment: Shortest distance is still very unclear. Do you mean minimum number of average genetic pairwise differences on putatively neutral sequences (which result will slightly depends on the alignment methods and consideration of gene/chromosome duplication/deletion)? Maybe you are referring to some other measure such as chosing a number of quantative traits and compute the average (over all traits) difference between species average trait value.

Comment: As you used the term "phylogenetic" in your question, it totally makes sense to consider the time to the MRCA as a measure of distance. It is what we mean when we talk about how closely related are two different lineages/species anyway. It will be a very very good proxy for the number of pairwise differences at neutral sequences also.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: by "time of branching", I suppose the oly thing you can mean is "time to the most recent common ancestor", which is exactly what I answered. Do you feel like my answer does not answer your question?

Comment: It doesn't answer, because it implies that all recent rodents and lagomorphs  "to a very good approximation" show the same number of pairwise differences at neutral sequences. Since this is counterintuitive (see my example of an "archaic" rodent (it does not live in Central Europe but just for the sake of this argument)). So the intermediate question would be: What kind of measure would allow us to make a distinction is distance between the relation between an "archaic" rodent and a more evolved one? Is the simplest answer already "number of pairwise differences at neutral sequences"?

Comment: The terms "archaic" and "more evolved" make little sense. You seem to assume there is a thing such as "distance between species" and then we try to estimate it with different statistics. The reality is that the term "distance between species" is undefined and you have to chose a statistics and make sense for your particular interest. The very standard is to consider the time to MRCA which is a very proxy anyway to many other statistics of species divergence such as typically the number of pairwise differences at neutral sequences. By the term "relatedness", we also refer to time to MRCA only.

Comment: If things are still unclear, I invite you to (1) follow an introductory course to phylogenetics and (2) ask your question regarding your misunderstanding about phylogenetics in a separate post as such discussion would be off-topic here. I you clarify your post by rewriting the question I suggested at the top of my answer (and remove the unclear concept of "next relative"), then you will be able to consider your question has been answered (and your post could well be re-opened).